# Download and save swf file on my server with php

Tags: php, parsing

I am parsing flash websites and wish to grab `swf` files from them.

My question is how to save the `swf` files on my server (rather than my computer) using PHP.

Comment: Run the script from your server? Otherwise look into php's http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php FTP functions, I assume you have FTP access to your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save any file with PHP using the [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function to get the raw data and the [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) function to save to disk. Make sure you have write access to the file location you use for `file_put_contents`.

Also for security reasons I would not store any of the files you retrieve like this in a path that can be executed directly. So try to store them below the document root.

```
<?php
$swffile = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/game.swf');
file_put_contents('localgame.swf', $swffile);
?>
```

Comment: thx Hugo Delsing this is right ! i cant mark your answer as my acceped answer :(